# Constraints break when programmatically customized UITableViewCell is removed from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am using `UITableViewController` and I am loading customized `UITableViewCell`. All elements in the cell and the constraints are configured programmatically. The TableView looks like this

[image]
All works perfectly except when deleting a cell. I configured the tableView to fade cells when deleted. However, the cell gives a little jerk movement then it goes to the left instead of fading, and I get auto layout error messages in the Console: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" for below

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002551a40 UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0.height == 100   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025505a0 V:|-(16)-[UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002550730 UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025605a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10.height == 1.19209e-07   (active)>"
```

and below

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025505a0 V:|-(16)-[UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002550730 UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025605a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10.height == 1.19209e-07   (active)>"
```

and that "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" for below

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002551a40 UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0.height == 100   (active)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002550730 UIView:0x7fccbd5286f0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccbd541b10.bottom   (active)>
```

> I broke the console output into parts because I couldn't paste it all together for some reason.

Basically, I have a `UIView` called `cellView` (the white corner rounded area) inside the `contentView` of the cell. And all other elements you see are inside the `cellView`. I applied below constraints between the `cellView` and `contentView`

```
cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cellView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
```

It worked when I tried deactivating all constraints in the cell and its subviews just before deleting the cell. But, when new cells are reused, they didn't have constraints to activate.

How should I handle this case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to  lower priority of bottom constraint

```
let con = cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)  
con.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
con.isActive = true
```

Comment: The app was terminated at launch - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Mutating a priority from required to not on an installed constraint (or vice-versa) is not supported.  You passed priority 999 and the existing priority was 1000.'`

Comment: can you swap priority and isactive lines and try

Comment: It worked, your order was correct, I just didn't follow your order the first time. Now I don't get any error messages in the console when deleting, but the cell still does not animate smoothly and always go to the left regardless what I set in the `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)`

Comment: this is interesting...  I voted this up because I had a similar problem. can you explain what is happening and why this resolves it? I am very curious. thanx.

Comment: @dniswhite the contentView of the table has an encapsulted height as a pre -setted value when the tableView loads that has a priority of 1000 which for sure won't be satisfied when there are number of constraints from top to bottom of the cell which are result in a different height value than the pre-setted one which will cause a conflict , so making the priority of the bottom constraint < 1000 will recover from this conflict until the table calculates the correct one from subviews of the cell then that 999  constraint will be satisfied without any breaks as the pre-con one is no longer exists

Comment: Works perfectly!! Tysm :)